# How to generate Index of user given value in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to set index to user given values in textbox and its appending to below table in newly created row but how to show that index in every row first column in my table? I am new to this type of functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('#addbtn').click(function(){
 
  var s = $.trim($('#user').val());
  var i = 0;
  var c = 1;
  var count = i+c;
if(s !=''){
  $('#result').attr('src','http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/abT/y4b/abTy4bcL7.png');
$('#usertbl').append('<tr height=\"30\">'+'<td>'+count+'</td>'+'<td>'+s+'</td>'+'<td>'+'</td>'+'</tr>');
}
$('#user').val(' ');

  
});
  
});
```

```css
table,tr,th,td{
border:1px solid #dddddd;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user"/>
<button id="addbtn">Add</button><span><img src="http://pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-9/256/cross-mark.png" id="result" height="50" width="50"/></span>
<table style="width:100%;" id="usertbl">
<tr height="30">
<th width="34%">Serial Number</th>
<th width="33%">User NAme</th>
<th width="33%">Content</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 
 $('#addbtn').click(function(){
  var s = $.trim($('#user').val());

  if(s !=''){
   $('#result').attr('src','http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/abT/y4b/abTy4bcL7.png');
   $('#usertbl').append('<tr height=\"30\">'+'<td>'+count+'</td>'+'<td>'+s+'</td>'+'<td>'+'</td>'+'</tr>');
   count++;
  }
  $('#user').val(' ');
 });

 $('#user').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').attr('src','http://pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-9/256/cross-mark.png');
 });
});
```

```css
table,tr,th,td{
 border:1px solid #dddddd;
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user"/>
<button id="addbtn">Add</button><span><img src="http://pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-9/256/cross-mark.png" id="result" height="50" width="50"/></span>

<table style="width:100%;" id="usertbl">
 <tr height="30">
  <th width="34%">Serial Number</th>
  <th width="33%">User NAme</th>
  <th width="33%">Content</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Decalre variable outside the click event and over ride it using increment when click.

Comment: after adding row how to change right mark as cross mark when user clicks on text box it will change .

Comment: After completing of appending of one row in table now user clicks on textbox then i want to change that img right mark as Cross mark

Comment: Look at it now. After 1 sec, it comes back.

Comment: its right but user when clicks on text box then it will changing want .

Comment: Edit your question. Put all you want then I will answer it. Don't ask one by one.

Answer (score 1):

declare i above click function.

ie- i=0;

Comment: after adding row how to change right mark as cross mark when user clicks on text box it will change

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of rows and use that for index

```
var $tbl = $('#usertbl');
var count = $('tr', $tbl).length;
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wbhuccd7/

Comment: after adding row how to change right mark as cross mark when user clicks on text box it will change

Comment: What do you mean? Change it back to "X" after the row is added? Can it be timed, like wait 2 seconds then change to "X"?